# Dealing with larger traffic on ASP.net web site

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net web site for our company and handles about 1000 - 2000 users every day.  Now the site will have about 4-5000 users every day.  We are putting it to two servers and put them in the hardware load balanced environment.

I am wondering if there is anything else I should do from the ASP.net web site perspective to handle the larger users.

Thanks.

Comment: 4-5000 users a day for a single decent windows server with IIS6/7 on it won't make it skip a beat.  We get 4-5000 (at least) users an hour.

Comment: Agree with @George. Unless you have real bottleneck code through lack of best practices, a single server should handle 400,000 visits a day with no sign of stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I'd take into consideration..

- Session state management - are you going to do it out-of-process?  If so, make sure everything being stored in Session is serializable.
- Do you have a large number (or any? some may argue) [update panels](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/) being used or many standard server-side postbacks?  If so, try to convert what you can to simple AJAX requests and marshal raw/JSON data back and forth.  This will minimize on the number of full page life cycles and data traffic on the server.
- On the front-end/UI side, try to leverage [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/), so that you go to the server for the images once and never again.
- For database connectivity, make sure you leverage [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).
- You may also want to consider js and css minification.

Additionally, these pages has some good tips:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx   (a bit outdated, but still somewhat relevant)

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should profile your application against bottleneck - if there is any place in your code which makes your application slow then adding new servers won't help. There are many profilers - I recommend JetBrains Dot Trace (there is a free trial for couple of days).

Second thing is OutputCache - the shortest explanation is "store html that is sent to the users, not recreate it every time. There is a huge number of articles about OutputCache so I don't think you need any link here.

If the traffic is even bigger you can think about using some solution for caching your responses around the world (read e.g. about Akamai) but I don't suppose you will need it with couple thousands of visitors daily.